# Using python selenium to choose an option from a dropdown menu with always changing values

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I am struggling with a code.

I want to choose an option from a dropdown menu, but the options' values are always different.

I was using this pseudo code I found here:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()="Some text"]").click()
```

This works for now, but the "Some text" is always changing, depending on the date.

This is the HTML of the dropdown menu (see picture attached). As described, the values change regarding the date, but the date always changes when I try to automate this to run once a day (obviously).

[image: dropdown HTML]

How can I solve this? Lets say I'd like to always choose the 6:30 pm option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a `<select>` tag, have you tried `Select()` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element like this (python example):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

object_time = datetime.today().replace(hour=6, minute=30, second=0)
object_name = object_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//option[value='{object_name}']").click()
```

Comment: I see. This might work. 
But I want to book the option always 2 days ahead. So if I run the code today, it should work on the 31st, if I run it tomorrow, it should work on the 1st. I hope this makes sense. Do you have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add 2 days to `object_time`. add the following at the end of line 3 `+ timedelta(days=2)`. Here the whole line: `object_time = datetime.today().replace(hour=6, minute=30, second=0) + timedelta(days=2)`

Comment: Thanks, it works so far but as I tried this, somehow I get this message:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//option[value='2021-12-30 18:30:00']"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)

although the value is exactly "2021-12-30 18:30:00". Why is it unable to locate it now?

Comment: This is the part of the code where I try to choose from the dropdown menu:

`dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "input-group")`
dropdown.click()
`#time.sleep(1)`
`object_time = datetime.today().replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=0) + timedelta(days=1)`
`object_name = object_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//option[value='{object_name}']").click()`

Comment: It worked when I used this code:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()='8:30pm Thu Dec 30th 2021']").click()`

but then I have the same problem with the changing text